# Apache VirtualHost Alias Issue with wildcard subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an issue with Aliases on Apache on Ubuntu 10.04.3

What I am trying to do is as follows :-

- One subdomain (mydomain.domain.com) on port 80 - that redirects to port 443 of mydomain.domain.com
- One subdomain (mydomain.domain.com) on port 443 with SSlEngine on
- Wildcard subdomains (*.domain.com) on port 80 - that redirects to port 443 of *.domain.com:443
- Wildcard subdomains (*.domain.com) on port 443 with SSlEngine on

I've got one file in /etc/apache2/sites-available folder

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
    DirectoryIndex index.cfm

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName mydomain.domain.com:443
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain
    DirectoryIndex index.cfm

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_/-]+)$ /index.cfm%{REQUEST_URI} [PT]


SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -all +SSLv3 +TLSv1
...
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName something.domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain_all
    DirectoryIndex index.cfm

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName something.domain.com:443
    ServerAlias *.domain.com:443
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain_all
    DirectoryIndex index.cfm

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/_/-]+)$ /index.cfm%{REQUEST_URI} [PT]


SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol -all +SSLv3 +TLSv1
...
...
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that all requests to anything.domain.com actually go to the first ssl VH ie mydomain.domain.com - have I got the order wrong? or something else wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a `NameVirtualHost *:443` directive for vhosts other than the first one on the port to function.

Depending on your Apache and OpenSSL versions, it may throw a warning during startup about multiple vhosts on an SSL port - feel free to ignore it.

Are you using the same certificate (hopefully a wildcard) for the two SSL vhosts, or different ones?  If they're different, then connecting clients that do not support SNI will always get the certificate for the first vhost.

Comment: NameVirtualHost *:80
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 80

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443 https
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443 https
    </IfModule>

Comment: The above is how my ports.conf looks like and It's the same Wildcard SSL cert on all subdomains. @ShaneMadden

Comment: @Jimmy Does Apache put any warnings or errors in the error log during startup?

Comment: No it does not. Also, the Apache version is 2.2.14

Comment: @Jimmy Well, if it's not warning about an issue with the host header mapping, or erroring with an issue on the SSL certificate or something, then it should be working just fine.  Are you absolutely sure the requests are being served by the wrong vhost?  They *are* both being sent to a copy of an index.cfm...

Comment: I can tell its only picking the first vhost because some images are in the wildcard VH and not in the mydomain.domain.com VH - but I get a 404 and looking at the logs it is clear that it is looking for the images in the mydomain.domain.com VH.

Comment: @Jimmy You don't have anything more concrete like access logs for the vhosts?  Can you provide the logs that are leading you to suspect this?